# my app stopped unfortunately due to no data entry into text

Tags: android, string, onclick

i build an android application on android studio, and it stopped unfortunately every time if i left the text empty with no numbers,

the logcat shows me this message when i didn't enter any number to my texts: 
**Choreographer﹕ Skipped 95 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread**

this is my equation :

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {


    float n1, n2, n3, n4;
    double result1, result2;

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Bwt);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Hit);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ibw);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abw);
    n1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
    n2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
    n3 = Float.parseFloat(Gender1.getText().toString());
    n4 = Float.parseFloat(Gender2.getText().toString());
    result1 = n3+(n4*((n2*0.3937007874)-60)) ;
    result2 = result1+(0.4*(n1-result1)) ;
    t1.setText(Double.toString(result1));
    DecimalFormat fresult = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
    String finaresult = fresult.format(result2);
    t2.setText(String.valueOf(finaresult));

}
```

Comment: What is expected behavior?

Comment: i enter numbers to the texts then when i press calc button the app works fine and do the equation "n3+(n4*((n2*0.3937007874)-60))", but if i left the texts empty and press the calc button it stopped ?!?

Comment: if there is nothing in your EditText and you press the button why would you expect it not to crash, you cannot convert a `Number` from `NOTHING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    float n1, n2, n3, n4;
    double result1, result2;

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Bwt);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Hit);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ibw);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abw);
    try {
        n1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
        n2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
        n3 = Float.parseFloat(Gender1.getText().toString());
        n4 = Float.parseFloat(Gender2.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Show message or something else
        return;
    }
    result1 = n3+(n4*((n2*0.3937007874)-60)) ;
    ...

}
```

You must catch NumberFormatException while calling `Float.parseFloat()`, `Integer.parseInt()` etc with user input.

Comment: of you could soft check like you should be doing instead of throwing unnecessary try/catches in

Comment: @fRoStBit :
told me this error msg on return :
"Missing return value"

Comment: @mohamdjado this error shouldn't be if the method returns void (in your code snippet it does: `public void onButtonClick`). But if it returns boolean, replace `return` with `return false`

Comment: again you help :) thx very much :), how can i make you happy like what i'm feeling now ...